# Graphing only certain lines in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an excel data sheet of thousands of lines of data separated by hundredths of seconds. I would like to graph but only use on line out of every 6,000 lines. Is this possible? To graph only a periodic line of data?

I have so much data that graphing it all just makes the graph convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a helper column.  Let’s say your data is in row 2 to 123456 and starts in column A.  In a new sheet or in an adjacent empty column use the following formula

```
=INDEX(A:A,(row($A1)-1)*6000+2)
```

Copy that formula down 21 rows (123456 ÷ 6000) and it will grab every 6000th row starting in row 2.  Copy it to the right to get the corresponding adjacent columns.  Then just graph the new data.

- A:A is the column you want to pull the number from
- row(A1) acts as a counter as it’s copied down and generates a sequence 1,2,3,4,5, etc.
- -1 makes the first row evaluate to 0
- 6000 is the number of row you want to jump each time
- +2 is the starting row of your data

Note if you put this formula on a separate sheet, you just need to change the `A:A` reference to `'sheet name'!A:A`.  Where sheet name is the name of the sheet of your source data.

Comment: This is possibly the best approach, but I disagree with the terminology.  You’re not talking about a “helper column” here.  A helper column is typically placed adjacent to the primary data and (almost always) stretches the length of the primary data.  I’m not sure whether there is a standard term for what you’re describing; I might call it an “alternative view”, an “abbreviated view”, or a “sample” of the primary data.

Comment: @Scott I have always used helper column as something that will store information between you initial data and your final results that you cant get away from by nesting formula, but to each their own.  In this case final result being the graph